# Exclude certain Models from Swashbuckle-generated Swagger Schema in ASP.Net Core OData Project

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, odata, swashbuckle

I am using Swashbuckle to generate the Swagger documentation for my ASP.Net Core 3.1 OData project.

The generation of the controllers' methods is perfect. And it is correctly generating the schema based on the models, except for one thing:

For each Model in the schema, it is also generating an additional `[ModelName]IQueryableODataValue` entry, as shown in the below screenshot:

[image: swagger doc screenshot]

The blue check indicates the model. The model entries circled in red are the superfluous entries that are also being added.

Note it is also generating the `Void` model, also circled in red.

How do I get the swagger documentation to omit the model entries that I have circled in red? I suspect it has something to do with adding a SchemaFilter. But I can't figure out how to apply it to resolve this issue.

EDIT:
@0909EM's comment lead me to do some digging into the SchemaFilter a bit more, and I ended up applying the following SchemaFilter:

```
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyProject.SwaggerConfig
{
    public class RemoveBogusDefinitions : ISchemaFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {
            foreach (var item in context.SchemaRepository.Schemas.Keys.Where(r => r.EndsWith("ODataValue")))
                context.SchemaRepository.Schemas.Remove(item);

            context.SchemaRepository.Schemas.Remove("Void");
        }
    }
}
```

It works as long as the LAST `schema` added to the `context` is a valid model that I want to keep.  The problem is that the above code executes, and then the `schema` is added to the `context`.  So if the last `schema` being processed happens to be one that I want to exclude, the above code won't do it.

How do I prevent a `schema` from being added to the `context`?

Comment: Does this help?
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/482

Comment: @0909EM That allows me to exclude a property from the Model, but what I am trying to achieve to exclude the Model completely.

Comment: Could you define a return type, as follows `[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(DebtCounsellorModel))]` such that an `DebtCounsellorModelODataValue` wouldn't be exposed in the first place?

Answer (score 9):

In my case only this worked:

```
internal class SwaggerSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        var keys = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
        var prefix = "My.Namespace";
        foreach(var key in context.SchemaRepository.Schemas.Keys)
        {
            if (key.StartsWith(prefix))
            {
                keys.Add(key);
            }
        }
        foreach(var key in keys)
        {
            context.SchemaRepository.Schemas.Remove(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Plus 1, this works, also adding a custom decorator/annotation to get the Models would be a nice way.

Answer (score 6):

I had a buch of these schemas because I had `ODataQueryOptions<Invoice> queryOptions` as an argument in controller action. I solved it with: `options.MapType(typeof(ODataQueryOptions<>), () => new ());` so you should be able to do the same with whatever is generating these for you.

Comment: Had exactly the same problem and a schema filter does not work here as all types from all properties of `ODataQueryOptions<>` are added too otherways and these are just to many to find and filter them using an `ISchemaFilter`

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue...

I tried orellabac's answer which did indeed remove the classes from the schema definition however is caused errors to show up when expanding some API methods.

Not an perfect solution but what I did to get around it was include a custom stylesheet with some CSS to hide the relevant items:

**startup.cs**

```
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        options.InjectStylesheet("/custom.css");
    });
```

**custom.css**

```
[id*="ODataValue"], #model-Void {
    display: none;
}
```

Obviously it will still be there in the swagger.json and the HTML is still there, but for someone looking at the swagger UI it certainly aids clarity.

Comment: Removing the properties from the schema also breaks client generation (since they need to be aware of the return types), so this seems to be the only way to achieve this without breaking functionality

Comment: Why would you want to remove the types from the swagger UI but not the schema? If the schema needs them, then wouldn't you want the documentation to be available?

Comment: @ChrisSchaller The models ending in ...ODataValue are not "real" models, though. ODataValue is a generic wrapper class that simply places the result data in a `Value` property (as that's how OData does it). So, it's a bit overkill to have two separate models in the UI for every model - one wrapped and one unwrapped.